# requests.post() is not working within on_message method of python websocketapp

Tags: python, post, websocket, python-requests

I wrote the `ding()` function to send message to a chat group in the APP DingTalk by Alibaba. The function sends message through posting the message to an url, something like `requests.post(url, message)`

When I run the following code(where the `requests.post()` is embedded in `on_message()`), the message I send through `ding()` wouldn't get through, and there is no error message. 
But when I use the function `ding()` alone, it works perfectly.
I am wondering if the `requests.post` in the `ding()` function is conflicting with the websocket connection.

`ding()` is defined as below:

```
def ding(subject_text):
    dingding_url = "https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=fe********************b1" 
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    post_data = {
        "msgtype": "text", 
        "text": {
            "content": subject_text+'#'
        },
        "at": {
            "atMobiles": ["185xxxx3281"]
        }
    }
    requests.post(dingding_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(post_data))
```

`ding()` is embedded in `on_message()` as below:

```
def on_message(ws, message): 
    try:
        ding(message)           
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

`on_message()` is used in the WebSocketApp below(where MySocketss is a subclass of WebSocketApp):

```
class MySocketss(WebSocketApp):
    def _send_ping(self, interval, event):
        while not event.wait(interval):
            self.sock.last_ping_tm = time.time()
            if self.sock:
                try:
                    self.sock.send('2')
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
                    break

ws = MySocketss('wss://sscpgoelik.jin10.com:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=%s' % a,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close)
```

The full code is below if you need more details and the full picture (though maybe irrelevant to the problem):

```
def ding(subject_text):
    dingding_url = "https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=feb01e99e53b6f7747455239d0ccc11525e57b8ef8bb1f7b5b16f0e17d25ebb1" 
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    post_data = {
        "msgtype": "text", 
        "text": {
            "content": subject_text+'#'
        },
        "at": {
            "atMobiles": ["185xxxx3281"]
        }
    }
    requests.post(dingding_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(post_data))


class MySocketss(WebSocketApp):
    def _send_ping(self, interval, event):
        while not event.wait(interval):
            self.sock.last_ping_tm = time.time()
            if self.sock:
                try:
                    self.sock.send('2')
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
                    break

def on_close(ws): 
  print("Connection closed ……")


def on_message(ws, message): 
    try:
        ding(message)           
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def on_error(ws, error): 
  print(error)

def on_open(ws): 
  ws.send('2probe')
  ws.send('5')
  ws.send('2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     s=requests.session()
     headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
     x = s.get('https://sscpgoelik.jin10.com:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mu6fSmG', headers=headers)
     a = re.compile('sid":"(.*?)"').findall(x.text)[0]
     s.get('https://sscpgoelik.jin10.com:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mu6fSp8&sid=%s' % a,
                     headers=headers)
     s.post('https://sscpgoelik.jin10.com:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mu6fSpS&sid=%s' % a,
                      headers=headers,data='27:420["switch_channel",-8200]')
     s.get('https://sscpgoelik.jin10.com:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mu6fSpU&sid=%s' % a,
                      headers=headers)

     ws = MySocketss('wss://sscpgoelik.jin10.com:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=%s' % a,
                     on_message=on_message,
                     on_error=on_error,
                     on_close=on_close)
     ws.on_open = on_open
     ws.run_forever(ping_interval=15)
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: Problem solved. There are two headers in the code, they conflict with each other. Now I put the headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"} in the function ding(), and it works fine now.

Comment: You could write this comment as an answer.